# Dagger 2 - injecting multiple objects of same type using @Named not working

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

**My module:**

```
@Module
public class TcpManagerModule {
    private ITcpConnection eventsTcpConnection;
    private ITcpConnection commandsTcpConnection;

    public TcpManagerModule(Context context) {
        eventsTcpConnection = new EventsTcpConnection(context);
        commandsTcpConnection = new CommandsTcpConnection(context);
    }

    @Provides
    @Named("events")
    public ITcpConnection provideEventsTcpConnection() {
        return eventsTcpConnection;
    }

    @Provides
    @Named("commands")
    public ITcpConnection provideCommandsTcpConnection() {
        return commandsTcpConnection;
    }
}
```

**Component:**

```
@Component(modules = TcpManagerModule.class)
public interface TcpManagerComponent {
    void inject(ITcpManager tcpManager);
}
```

**class where injection happens:**

```
public class DefaultTcpManager implements ITcpManager {
    private TcpManagerComponent tcpComponent;

    @Inject @Named("events") ITcpConnection eventsTcpConnection;

    @Inject @Named("commands") ITcpConnection commandsTcpConnection;

    public DefaultTcpManager(Context context){
        tcpComponent = DaggerTcpManagerComponent.builder().tcpManagerModule(new TcpManagerModule(context)).build();
        tcpComponent.inject(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void startEventsConnection() {
        eventsTcpConnection.startListener();
        eventsTcpConnection.connect();
    }
}
```

When I call `startEventsConnection`, I get `NullPointerException` - meaning the injection didn't populate the fields.

I followed the example exactly the way it is on the Docs, what is the issue?

*Note:* on the **builder** line

```
tcpComponent = DaggerTcpManagerComponent.builder().tcpManagerModule(new TcpManagerModule(context)).build();
```

I have a warning saying "tcpManagerModule is deprecated". I read the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36521366/1662033) about this issue, and its saying

> It is safe to say that you can just ignore the deprecation. It is intended to notify you of unused methods and modules. As soon as you actually require / use Application somewhere in your subgraph the module is going to be needed, and the deprecation warning will go away.

So, am I not requiring/using the instances? What is the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try changing your `Component` defining the specific class for injection:

```
@Component(modules = TcpManagerModule.class)
public interface TcpManagerComponent {
    void inject(DefaultTcpManager tcpManager);
}
```

So that Dagger knows exactly about `DefaultTcpManager.class`.