# Dagger2 - "Unused" Modules in Generated Component Class

Tags: android, dagger-2

My Dagger2 Component class contains 3 modules which I'm trying to use to inject field dependencies into an Android Activity class. The generated Component file has comments saying all the modules are unused, linking this [page](https://google.github.io/dagger/unused-modules) for more info.

My Activity class is calling the Component's inject(Activity) method and has fields annotated for injection that are provided by the modules, so I am not sure why the generated Component file does not have any Providers to do this injection.

My code is below, thanks for the help!

**Generated Component Class:**

```
public final class DaggerMainComponent implements MainComponent {
      private DaggerMainComponent(Builder builder) {
        assert builder != null;
      }

  public static Builder builder() {
    return new Builder();
  }

  public static MainComponent create() {
    return builder().build();
  }

  @Override
  public void inject(Activity activity) {
    MembersInjectors.<Activity>noOp().injectMembers(activity);
  }

  public static final class Builder {
    private Builder() {}

    public MainComponent build() {
      return new DaggerMainComponent(this);
    }

    /**
     * @deprecated This module is declared, but an instance is not used in the component. This method is a no-op. For more, see https://google.github.io/dagger/unused-modules.
     */
    @Deprecated
    public Builder daoModule(DaoModule daoModule) {
      Preconditions.checkNotNull(daoModule);
      return this;
    }

    /**
     * @deprecated This module is declared, but an instance is not used in the component. This method is a no-op. For more, see https://google.github.io/dagger/unused-modules.
     */
    @Deprecated
    public Builder repositoryModule(RepositoryModule repositoryModule) {
      Preconditions.checkNotNull(repositoryModule);
      return this;
    }

    /**
     * @deprecated This module is declared, but an instance is not used in the component. This method is a no-op. For more, see https://google.github.io/dagger/unused-modules.
     */
    @Deprecated
    public Builder portableModule(PortableModule portableModule) {
      Preconditions.checkNotNull(portableModule);
      return this;
    }
  }
}
```

**Non-Generated Component Class**:

```
@Component(modules={DaoModule.class,RepositoryModule.class,PortableModule.class})
public interface MainComponent {
    void inject(Activity activity);
}
```

**Module Classes**:
Is there any issue with having one module provide an object with a dependency on another object provided by another module belonging to the same Component?

```
@Module
public class DaoModule {

    private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

    public DaoModule(DatabaseHelper databaseHelper){
        this.databaseHelper = databaseHelper;
    }

    @Provides
    public Dao<Player,Integer> providePlayerDao(){
        return databaseHelper.getPlayerDao();
    }

    @Provides
    public Dao<GamePlayed,Integer> provideGamePlayedDao() {
        try {
            return databaseHelper.getDao(GamePlayed.class);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Provides
    public Dao<GamePlayer,Integer> provideGamePlayerDao() {
        try {
            return databaseHelper.getDao(GamePlayer.class);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

...

@Module
public class RepositoryModule {

    @Provides
    public IGameResultRepository provideGameResultRepository(
            Dao<Player,Integer> playerDao,
            Dao<GamePlayed,Integer> gameDao,
            Dao<GamePlayer, Integer> gamePlayerDao)
    {
        return new OrmliteGameResultRepository(playerDao,gameDao,gamePlayerDao);
    }
}

@Module
public class PortableModule {

    @Provides
    public GameResultListener provideGameResultListener(IGameResultRepository gameResultRepository){
        return new GameResultListener(gameResultRepository);
    }

}
```

**Application Class:**

```
public class AppStart extends Application {

    private MainComponent mainComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());

        mainComponent = DaggerMainComponent.builder()
                .daoModule(new DaoModule(databaseHelper))
                .build();
    }

    public MainComponent getMainComponent(){
        return mainComponent;
    }
}
```

**Activity Class:**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Inject GameResultListener gameResultListener;
    @Inject Dao<Player,Integer> dao;
    @Inject IGameResultRepository repository;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle state) {
        super.onCreate(state);

        ((AppStart)this.getApplication()).getMainComponent().inject(this);
```

Comment: What is your Dagger version

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dagger 2.2 component builder module method deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36521302/dagger-2-2-component-builder-module-method-deprecated)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Question 1:** Why are my modules being marked as "unused"?

You have not supplied the correct injection site! As it stands, your component interface is one with the sole injection site of `android.app.Activity`. Since `android.app.Activity` has no `@Inject` annotations on its fields then you get a no-op members injector. Similarly, your modules are marked as unused because none of them are actually being used as sources of dependencies for `android.app.Activity`. To fix this, in your component change:

```
void inject(Activity activity);
```

to:

```
void inject(MyActivity myActivity);
```

**Question 2:**

> Is there any issue with having one module provide an object with a dependency on another object provided by another module belonging to the same Component?

No, this is perfectly fine. To illustrate, let's take a simple object graph:

```
public class Foo {

    public Foo(FooDependency fooDependency) {}
}

public class FooDependency {

    FooDependency(String name) {}
}
```

We want to inject it inside the following class using Dagger:

```
public class FooConsumer {

    @Inject Foo foo;

    private FooConsumer() {}
}
```

We would like to reuse a module binding `FooDependency` so we'll write two separate modules:

```
@Module
public class FooModule {

    @Provides
    Foo foo(FooDependency fooDependency) {
        return new Foo(fooDependency);
    }
}

@Module
public class FooDependencyModule {

    @Provides
    FooDependency fooDependency() {
        return new FooDependency("name");
    }
}
```

And the following component interface:

```
@Component(modules = {FooModule.class, FooDependencyModule.class})
public interface FooComponent {
    void inject(FooConsumer fooConsumer);
}
```

The generated component `DaggerFooComponent` contains the following code that will correctly use the `FooDependency` from the separate module `FooDependencyModule` to inject `Foo`:

```
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  private void initialize(final Builder builder) {

    this.fooDependencyProvider =
        FooDependencyModule_FooDependencyFactory.create(builder.fooDependencyModule);

    this.fooProvider = FooModule_FooFactory.create(builder.fooModule, fooDependencyProvider);

    this.fooConsumerMembersInjector = FooConsumer_MembersInjector.create(fooProvider);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering both questions. Injections not being made for subclasses of the inject() parameters is very subtle