# activityModule is deprecated | dagger2

Tags: android, deprecated, dagger-2, deprecation-warning

I got a very [**useful**](https://blog.mindorks.com/introduction-to-dagger-2-using-dependency-injection-in-android-part-2-b55857911bcd) blog to start my hand with Dagger2. All going I guess going pretty well except an deprecate warning about to `Builder.addModule()`.

I got this link about **[Unused Modules and Component Dependencies](https://google.github.io/dagger/unused-modules)** link related but it still not clear to me.

> When the Dagger processor generates components, it only requires
>   instances of modules and component dependencies that are explicitly
>   needed to supply requests for a binding.

Any one know if any alternative of this deprecated method ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dagger 2.2 component builder module method deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36521302/dagger-2-2-component-builder-module-method-deprecated)

Comment: If this does not answer your question please add further details about what exactly is not clear to you and maybe include the module / component in question, along with its usages.